# Как сделать массив у поля JSON объекта?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Возникла такая проблема. Я могу передавать JSON объект формата

```
[
  {
    "title": "test",
    "address": "55.99752311227003,49.08959250252893"
  },
  {
    "title": "test122",
    "address": "63.08891623673952,46.243883499999946"
  },
  {
    "title": "test1111",
    "address": "55.69684742706125,37.59635133512744"
  },
  {
    "title": "kgeu",
    "address": "55.816852257889856,49.09529045886616"
  }
]
```

Но нужно получить JSON объект формата

```
[ 
 {
    "title": "kgeu",
    "address": [55.816852257889856,49.09529045886616]
 }
]
```

setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
),
 'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
)
}
```

serializers.py

```
class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = ['title', 'address']
```

views.py

```
class FactoryListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Factory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FactorySerializer
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    address = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = ['title', 'address']

    def get_address(self, obj):
        return [float(i) for i in obj.address.split(',')]
```